# Java: Error: <rect> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN"./ Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an error while representing my data through a bar chart graph with `D3JS` . Even if I see that logically, everything is right:

the X axis show gets the whole values of X and Y, ad the errors are:
Error:  attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".
Error:  attribute height: Expected length, "NaN".
here's My code and my data:

```
    function HGlob(){


    var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 850 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")


    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return d.somme;
      })


    var svg = d3.select("#countries").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.call(tip);


    d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Zone_Geographique; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.somme; })]);


      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)


      svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Zone_Geographique); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.somme); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.somme); })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

    });

    function type(d) {
      d.somme = +d.somme;
      return d;
    }
    }

    /*callign the HGlob fucntion*/
    var HGlobal=HGlob();

/** data tsv file **/
Zone_Geographique   annee1  annee2  annee3  somme
Europe_hors Schengen  473947  525119  582245  1581311
Maghreb  377022  415607  472250  1264879
Asie_océanie  436002  464936  513985  1414923
Moyen_orient  310525  352504  336209  999238
afrique_francophone  163944  151661  155352  470957
afrique_non_francophone  112027  113830  125657  351514
amérique_latine_Caraïbes  67571  66980  66298  200849
amérique_du_nord  52975  57392  51452  161819
Europe_Schengen  5399  8162  7812  21373
```

Comment: It's because the data in your tsv isn't tab separated, it's spaces, Change it to tabs and it should work

Comment: How can i change it to tab, it's a TSV file and not a CSV file, i don't know  from where should i choose the tab option!

Comment: In most text editors when you press the tab key you get a tab  character, if you're unsure and you're on a windows os you can open up notepad and press tab once, copy the tab character an replace the spaces in your tsv file with it.

Comment: Alright, i'll try it and tell you if it works